# How to make the phone number unique in WordPress

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

I have added 3 custom field on woocommerce registration page.

My code so far:-

```
/* Add Extra Registration Field in Woocommerce */

//Add First Name, Last Name, and Phone Number
function woocom_extra_register_fields() {?>
       <p class="form-row form-row-wide">
       <label for="reg_billing_phone"><?php _e( 'Phone', 'woocommerce' ); ?><span class="required">*</span></label>
       <input type="text" class="input-text" name="billing_phone" id="reg_billing_phone" value="<?php esc_attr_e( $_POST['billing_phone'] ); ?>" />
       </p>
       <p class="form-row form-row-first">
       <label for="reg_billing_first_name"><?php _e( 'First name', 'woocommerce' ); ?><span class="required">*</span></label>
       <input type="text" class="input-text" name="billing_first_name" id="reg_billing_first_name" value="<?php if ( ! empty( $_POST['billing_first_name'] ) ) esc_attr_e( $_POST['billing_first_name'] ); ?>" />
       </p>
       <p class="form-row form-row-last">
       <label for="reg_billing_last_name"><?php _e( 'Last name', 'woocommerce' ); ?><span class="required">*</span></label>
       <input type="text" class="input-text" name="billing_last_name" id="reg_billing_last_name" value="<?php if ( ! empty( $_POST['billing_last_name'] ) ) esc_attr_e( $_POST['billing_last_name'] ); ?>" />
       </p>
       <div class="clear"></div>
       <?php
 }
 add_action( 'woocommerce_register_form_start', 'woocom_extra_register_fields' );


//Validate Fields
function woocom_validate_extra_register_fields( $username, $email, $validation_errors ) {

      if ( isset( $_POST['billing_first_name'] ) && empty( $_POST['billing_first_name'] ) ) {

             $validation_errors->add( 'billing_first_name_error', __( '<strong>Error</strong>: First name is required!', 'woocommerce' ) );

      }

      if ( isset( $_POST['billing_last_name'] ) && empty( $_POST['billing_last_name'] ) ) {

             $validation_errors->add( 'billing_last_name_error', __( '<strong>Error</strong>: Last name is required!.', 'woocommerce' ) );

      }
      if ( isset( $_POST['billing_phone'] ) && empty( $_POST['billing_phone'] ) ) {

             $validation_errors->add( 'billing_phone_error', __( '<strong>Error</strong>: Mobile number is required!.', 'woocommerce' ) );

      }
         return $validation_errors;
}

add_action( 'woocommerce_register_post', 'woocom_validate_extra_register_fields', 10, 3 );



//Save Fields
function woocom_save_extra_register_fields( $customer_id ) {
    if ( isset( $_POST['billing_phone'] ) ) {
                 // Phone input filed which is used in WooCommerce
                 update_user_meta( $customer_id, 'billing_phone', sanitize_text_field( $_POST['billing_phone'] ) );
          }
      if ( isset( $_POST['billing_first_name'] ) ) {
             //First name field which is by default
             update_user_meta( $customer_id, 'first_name', sanitize_text_field( $_POST['billing_first_name'] ) );
             // First name field which is used in WooCommerce
             update_user_meta( $customer_id, 'billing_first_name', sanitize_text_field( $_POST['billing_first_name'] ) );
      }
      if ( isset( $_POST['billing_last_name'] ) ) {
             // Last name field which is by default
             update_user_meta( $customer_id, 'last_name', sanitize_text_field( $_POST['billing_last_name'] ) );
             // Last name field which is used in WooCommerce
             update_user_meta( $customer_id, 'billing_last_name', sanitize_text_field( $_POST['billing_last_name'] ) );
      }

}
add_action( 'woocommerce_created_customer', 'woocom_save_extra_register_fields' );




/* END Add Extra Registration Field in Woocommerce */
```

Everything is working fine but the problem is that its accepting the dupliacte phone numbers. How can i make the phone number field unique? Any idea will be really appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: JQuery should help you to prevent duplicate values.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to use a get_users function by meta_value if value exists execute validation:

```
 if ( isset( $_POST['billing_phone'] ) && empty( $_POST['billing_phone'] ) ) {
             $validation_errors->add( 'billing_phone_error', __( '<strong>Error</strong>: Mobile number is required!.', 'woocommerce' ) );

      }
if ( isset( $_POST['billing_phone'] ) ) {
   $hasPhoneNumber= get_users('meta_value='.$_POST['billing_phone']);
   if ( !empty($hasPhoneNumber)) {
     $validation_errors->add( 'billing_phone_error', __( '<strong>Error</strong>: Mobile number is already used!.', 'woocommerce' ) );
   }
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much buxbeatz.. You saved my life :)